# Is it possible to develop applications on Windows using MonoTouch/Xamarin?

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I know I need a mac to deploy but can I at least use my PC to develop the application? It would really help me a lot if I can develop on Windows where I can focus on writing the app.

Comment: You can use Xamarin in Windows with Visual Studio. See: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows

Comment: Thanks alot. Btw I last checked MonoTouch stuff 2 years ago. Do you know if I even need a mac to deploy? Maybe their is just no need for it either.

Comment: Sorry I don't know MonoTouch

Comment: yes you need a mac for mac applications

Comment: @MUG4N monotouch is old name of Xamarin

Comment: if your app is not complex, you can check for PhoneGap, its free based html javascript css etc

Comment: @MustafaEkici: Thanks, it's simple. I will check out phonegap too.

Comment: yes i worked before with phonegap, its perfect, powerfull.. if performance and security is not important for you, you can choose it... and you can add design your mobile application with jquerymobile too. cheers

Answer (score 3):

This answer covers only Xamarin 2.0. Unfortunately I don't know MonoTouch.
Take a look at this statement about Xamarin 2.0:

> Xamarin 2.0 bundles the company's Android, iOS and Mac development
>   tools in a single affordable package aimed at all tiers of developers.
>   The free Starter edition includes the Xamarin Studio IDE enables
>   developers to create Android, iOS and Mac apps using C#. However, the
>   free edition doesn't allow developers to exceed 32k of compiled IL
>   code and it cannot import or call upon any third-party libraries. The
>   $299 Indie edition removes this restriction. Things start getting
>   really interesting for .NET developers with Xamarin Studio's $999
>   Business edition. This version adds the ability to code iOS
>   applications within Visual Studio. **Yes, you read correctly — code
>   iOS applications in Visual Studio! Granted, you still need a Mac to
>   compile and deploy the application to iOS devices (more on that
>   later), but the fact that you can use a familiar IDE to develop iOS
>   applications is a game changer.**

To make it short: Yes you will need a mac to deploy your application and
                  yes you can develop on windows using Visual Studio.

Source: http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/xamarin-20-review/240150634

Comment: Thanks, I am download it now. I hope I don't need the $1k edition to compile on windows though.

Comment: I think Xamarin is the new name for MonoTouch.

Comment: well if your application doesn't exceed 32k of compiled IL code and does not call upon any third-party libraries you can use the free edition

Comment: Thanks yeah but the documentation seems to mention that I need a networked mac to compile. I hope that's not the case. If I can test my app inside the emulator, that's fine.

Comment: With the Business Edition of Xamarin.iOS, you can code in Visual Studio but you still MUST use a Mac as a build and deployment server.  Apple's SDK and device simulator ONLY run on a Mac.  The cheaper editions of Xamarin.iOS do not have the Visual Studio option.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need the 1 k version to compile on windows. When you want to deploy your app you need to buy it! If u are making a app for windows 8 or whatever you dont need to pay. Monogame is a open source project. For the deployment to the phones your paying to the xamarin project.

Comment: Thanks yeah but the documentation seems to mention that I need a networked mac to compile. I hope that's not the case. If I can test my app inside the emulator, that's fine.

Comment: I never tried for ios. But for android i could test it in their emulator. So i am assuming it works the same for IOS

Comment: Thanks need to contact them though because it complains that my "subscription" expired.

Answer (score 1):

"This means that your Xamarin iOS for Visual Studio installation requires a networked Mac OS-X computer to perform these tasks for you. Once configured, Xamarin’s tools will make the process as seamless as possible, but the fact remains that a Mac is required in addition to the Windows computer running Visual Studio."

So still need to hook up my mac and perform all the installations and configurations. Will take time but not a deal breaker I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use cloud build services for such a task. One such service worth giving a try is http://ship.io - they offer a free plan to get started.